# Auto Calculate QTY in openerp POS front view

Tags: javascript, odoo

I had add in two new column. Weight and Cart Weight. I am not familiar with Javascript, I would like to make whenever the weight and the cart weight had modify, The javascript will automatic calculate the QTY. I manage to modify the Weight and Cart weight but I am not managen to update the QTY column．

Let me explain more. I know this javascript function will update the value.

```
setValue: function(val) {
            var param = {};
            param[this.numpadState.get('mode')] = val;
            var order = this.shop.get('selectedOrder');
            if (order.get('orderLines').length !== 0) {
               order.selected.set(param);
            } else {
                this.shop.get('selectedOrder').destroy();
            }
```

Either before or after the line

```
order.selected.set(param);
```

I would like to add the action of calculate the QTY and update the field.

Comment: +1, this ***has*** to be upvoted for changing the font into something that horrible, and it even matches the username. Oh My Freaking God !!!

Comment: You should first modify the font weight.

Comment: Sorry, I don't aware of that.